# Creating folders based on posted hashtags PHP

Tags: php

So this is my first time posting a question on this website and as a programmer I'm ashamed I didn't create an account sooner, this website has gotten me through a lot lol, anyways enough about that, I need some help.

I am creating a system where users can post their own little statuses, update their status, share, etc. I need help creating folders for #hashtags based on the hashtag the user has in his posted status.

So an example would be: "*Hello world #firstpost #helloworld*", the code would have to exclude everything in that sentence except for any and all hashtags, and it would then create the folders for **all** the hashtags that are in the users post, in this case it's going to create the folders **firstpost** and **helloworld** (if they don't already exist).

Can I create the folders using a modified version of this or at least something better/similar/related?

```
$foldername = $_POST["status_posting"];
mkdir('../hashtag/' . $foldername, 0755);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
    mkdir('../users/' . $foldername, 0755);
}
```

Thank you for your guys help in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for a critique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to capture the hashtags, then use `mkdir()` to create the directories. You can use `file_exists()` to check if a file exists (or not `!`).

I would use the following expression: `#(\S{1,})`. This expression looks for a `#`, then starts capturing any non white-space character (`/S`), from once to infinite times (`{1,}`).

```
<?php
    $input = "Hello world #firstpost #helloworld";

    preg_match_all("/#(\S{1,})/", $input, $matches);

    foreach($matches[1] as $match){
        if (!file_exists('../hashtag/' . $match)) {
            mkdir('../hashtag/' . $match, 0755, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this also remove the "#" or would you need a str replace?

Comment: You can use `#(\S{1,})` to capture only the words, and then `$matches[1]` to get them from the array. I'll put them both in my answer.

Comment: Fantastic, the second one is what I think most if not everyone would be looking for. Thank you very much Daniel, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: It's best that you keep each question related to the question at hand. You can open a new question. I now realise the purpose for your question, and you are thinking about it the wrong way. You should use .htaccess and route the requests through a central file (hashtag being action, firstpost being the data)  and handle them there. If you're going that deep, may as well use some sort of MVC framework.

Comment: I answered my own question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd `php explode()` the message, check each item if it contains a `#`, if so mkdir the item's name minus the `#`. Possibly not the most efficient way to do it.

```
$foldername = explode(" ", $_POST["status_posting"]);
foreach($foldername as $string){
  if(strpos($string, '#') !== FALSE){
    //Make dir!
    mkdir('../hashtag/' . ltrim($string, "#"), 0755, true);
  }
}
```

The `true` at the end of mkdir allows for recursive file path creation. For instance, if the hashtag folder has not been created yet, it will create that too.

After doing some research, since "#" can be found without using regex, it's much more efficient to use `strpos() and explode()`. `preg_match() vs strpos()` speed is shown below.

```
no. strings  1        2       3         10      100     1000    10000
strpos()     0.01 ms  0.02 ms 0.04 ms   0.2 ms  0.9 ms  2.6 ms  25.6 ms
preg_match() 0.2 ms   0.2 ms  0.3 ms    0.47 ms 0.95 ms 7.4 ms  72.2 ms
```

Though you do have to factor in explode() time, the php forum states that explode() should be used when regex power is not required, for reasons we can see above. I would be interested in seeing the two answers code put head to head as it would be quite interesting to know for sure.

Comment: `explode()` requires two parameters!

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, edited it in, missed out the space to place the dynamite (:

I also believe it is faster to use `explode()` and then `strpos()` instead of Regex

Comment: `strpos()` vs `preg_match()` is related to a different circumstance. For example, using them both to find a specific word in a string. I don't doubt that it would likely still be faster to `explode()` and `strpos()` than `preg_match()`, but it will be negligible. Plus, the OP didn't express any concerns over performance (far less millisecond differences).

Comment: @Daniel While the poster may not have, there are other users that will visit this post in the future who may care about performance. I simply am offering an alternative option, which may be better for certain use cases where either a large amount of data is to be processed and such (: